# Is it possible to load two different csv files as two structured streams (two tables) within the same spark session

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I would like to confirm if it is possible/fine to read two different CSV files as structured streams into two different streaming dataframes?

Eg.

File1.csv (will keep coming in different parts in Folder1)
File2.csv (will keep coming in different parts in Folder2)

I create two dataframes by reading the above i.e Table1DF and Table2DF, and then do some transformations using Spark SQL using Table1DF and Table2DF

I want to do this as a part of same spark session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. There will be 2 different streaming queries. You can create as many streaming queries, but if one fails, it halts the whole job and hence it will affect other streaming queries as well.